# The class only takes 1 argument, but 4 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I keep getting the below error:

```
TypeError: PetLog() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given
```

when I run this:

```
pet_1 = ShelterPets('shelby', 'poodle', 'medium sized and white', df)
```

My code is this:

```
def ShelterPets(PetLog):
    def __init__(
        self, 
        pet_name: str, 
        pet_breed: str,
        description: str,
        pet_dataframe
    ):

        super().__init__(
            pet_name=pet_name,
            pet_adoption='shelter',
            pet_breed=pet_breed,
            description=description,
            pet_dataframe=pet_dataframe
        )
        
    def pet_codes(self):
        pet_code_list = self.pet_dataframe['pet_code'].tolist()
        self.pet_code_id = pet_code_list
```

This is the parent class it inherits:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class PetLog(ABC):
    def __init__(
        self,
        pet_name: str,
        pet_adoption: str, 
        pet_breed: str,
        description: str,
        pet_dataframe
    ):

        self.pet_name = pet_name
        self.pet_adoption = pet_adoption
        self.pet_breed = pet_breed
        self.description = description
        self.pet_dataframe = pet_dataframe
        
        self.pet_code_id = None
        
    @abstractmethod
    def pet_codes(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def pet_food(self):
        pass
```

I have checked for proper indentation, I have checked for syntax, I also have checked to make sure everything is in the right order. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @user202729 it's a built in module that lets me use the abstract class method

Comment: You are trying to use `def` to declare a class.

Comment: @Selcuk would you be able to clarify? Thank you

Comment: Your `def ShelterPets(PetLog):` line should be `class ShelterPets(PetLog):`

Comment: @Selcuk oh wow, thank you! I think this is what happens when you stare at code for too long 